# Unix: programmatically checking process existence by name AND process id

Tags: c++, unix, process, kill

I would like to define a method called:

```
bool checkIfProcessExists(pid_t processId, const std::string &processName)
{
   return 0 == kill(processId, 0);
}
```

The deficiency with the code above is that it could provide a false positive. (i.e. the processId does in fact exist, but it is a different process than the one I am interested in, namely, "processName")

How could I change the code so that it checks for BOTH the processId (first parameter) and processName (second parameter)?

I would prefer to AVOID solutions using "grep" (or related)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you also don't have access to `pgrep`?

Comment: gpojd, there is no access to pgrep (But that is irrelevant anyways, I believe, since I would prefer not to use any "grep" type solutions)

Comment: (I've updated my original question now to be more clear)

Comment: If you have a `/proc` file system, you can validate the process via that.  The details depend on the o/s you are using, though. Linux is powerful and informative; Solaris less so, Mac OS X doesn't have it, etc.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, Is there an api to access the "/proc" (or would I have to manually traverse it)?

Comment: manual traversal; but as you have the pid, you can open the `/proc/<pid>/comm` file, which contains the command line used for running the program. This is very much a linux oriented solution

Comment: Petesh, I tried this on a SGI system, and /proc/<pid> is a file instead of a directory.  It has permissions "600" (-rw---------), but I get "permission denied" when I try to open this file.   This looks like a workable solution though (as soon as I figure out the permissions problem)